# Как закрыть, перезагрузить и завершить сеанс Windows с помощью bat-файла?

Tags: windows, bat

Для доступа на рабочую станцию я использую [Remote Desktop Connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Remote_Desktop_Connection), но при этом знаю как выполнить закрытие/перезагрузку, как из меню «Пуск».

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[How do I shutdown - restart - logoff Windows via a bat file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162304/)» [@Keng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/730/).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162304/how-do-i-shutdown-restart-logoff-windows-via-a-bat-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя следующие команды вы можете завершить Windows с помощью bat–файла:

- `shutdown -r` — перезагрузка
- `shutdown -s` — закрытие
- `shutdown -l` — завершение сеанса
- `shutdown -t xx` — где `xx` — кол-во секунд ожидания до закрытия/перезагрузки/конца сеанса
- `shutdown -i` — выдаёт диалоговое окно для указания, какой функцией вы хотите воспользоваться
- `shutdown -a` — сбрасывает предыдущую команду закрытия Windows. Очень удобно!
- `shutdown -h` — режим сна. **Распространённая ошибка: это не вызов файла справки!**

**Дополнение**

Если вы работаете с удалённого компьютера, бывает полезно добавить опцию -f для **принудительной** перезагрузки. В противном случае, ваша сессия может завершиться и «упрямое» приложение приведёт к сбою в системе.

Когда мне нужно произвести немедленную перезагрузку, я использую следующее:

```
shutdown -t 0 -r -f
```

Если действовать более мягко, оставляя некоторое время перед перезагрузкой, можно воспользоваться следующей командой:

```
shutdown -t 30 -r
```

Как можно понять из комментариев, отсрочка закрытия по умолчанию предполагает -f.

**Дополнение 2**

Также существует опция `-m` для удалённого закрытия Windows:

```
shutdown -r -f -m \\machinename
```

- Параметр `-r` вызывает перезагрузку (что, как правило, подходит при работе с удалённой машиной, поскольку её физический запуск может оказаться затруднительным).
- Параметр `-f` вызывает принудительную перезагрузку.
- Естественно, для закрытия системы на удалённой машине вы должны иметь соответствующие права доступа.

**Дополнение 3**

У вас также есть вся серия <del>"**`rundll32.exe shell32.dll`**"</del> (пожалуйста, перед использование посмотрите секцию **НО**, так как использовать данный подход с большой вероятностью не стоит):

- `rundll32.exe user.exe,**ExitWindows**` [Быстрое закрытие Windows]
- `rundll32.exe user.exe,**ExitWindowsExec**` [Перезагрузка Windows]

  ```
    rundll32.exe shell32.dll,SHExitWindowsEx n
  ```

где `n` принимает следующие значения:

- 0 - `LOGOFF`
- 1 - `SHUTDOWN`
- 2 - `REBOOT`
- 4 - `FORCE`
- 8 - `POWEROFF`

(значения можно комбинировать -> 6 = 2+4 `FORCE REBOOT`)

**НО!**

[1800 INFORMATION](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3146/1800-information) любезно замечает [в комментариях](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162304/how-do-i-shutdown-restart-or-log-off-windows-via-a-bat-file/162398#162398):

> Не используйте для вашей цели `rundll32.exe`. `rundll32.exe` ожидает, что функция, передаваемая вами в командной строке, имеет точно заданную сигнатуру метода, которая может не совпадать с сигнатурой метода `ExitWindows`.

[Raymond CHEN](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/) писал:

- в 2004 «[Что может пойти не так, когда вы нарушаете соглашение о вызове?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040115-00/?p=41043)»:

> Сигнатура функции, необходимая для функций, вызываемых `rundll32.exe` такова:

```
void CALLBACK ExitWindowsEx(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst,
      LPSTR pszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
```

> Это не останавливает некоторых от использования `rundll32` для вызова произвольных функций, не предназначенных для вызова `rundll32, например,` user32 LockWorkStation`и`user32 ExitWindowsEx`.

(Упс.)

> Вот настоящая сигнатура функции для ExitWindowsEx :

```
BOOL WINAPI ExitWindowsEx(UINT uFlags, DWORD dwReserved);
```

- в 2011: «[Бросая мусор на обочину: печальная история программы rundll32](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110909-00/?p=9683)»

И для полной ясности:

- в 2013 «[Когда целесообразно использовать rundll32? Ответ прост: не используйте её!](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643)»:

> `Rundll32` - отголосок прошлого, оставшийся от Windows 95 и устаревший как минимум во времена Windows Vista из-за того, что нарушает множество современных технических принципов.

<sub>Перевод ответов [@Keng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/162305/564240), [@JosephStyons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/162342/564240), [@VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/162398/564240).</sub>